# Get 24 Hour time format in datetime variable

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am using `DateTime.TryParseExact` function to get the datetime value in variable using following code

```
 DateTime dt;
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
 System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
 string[] format = new string[] { "d/MMM/yy H:m:s tt","d-MMM-yy H:m:s tt" }; 
 string strDate = "24-May-13 12:03:03 AM";
 DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, format, provider, style, out dt);
```

Now what it does it parse the datetime correctly and give me result `24-May-2013 12:03:03`
But i want it should return me like this `24-May-2013 00:03:033`

How can i do this ?

Comment: Are you sure that's a *parsing* issue and not just a *display* issue?

Comment: On debug `dt` shows me `24-May-2013 12:03:03` which is somewhat wrong as time was in AM

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Can you check the `Hour` property of that `DateTime`, is it 12 or 0?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is showing 12 !!!

Comment: Can you post a program that actually compiles and runs? The program doesn't compile (no `dt` declared, `StrDate` vs. `strDate`), and it doesn't run either, `TryParseExact` returns false. Try posting a program that can be pasted into LINQPad or ideone.com and executed.

Comment: No, he said `Hour` is showing 12, which means it's mid-day. 12 AM is midnight.

Comment: Try using lowercase `h` instead of `H`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the lower-case `h` for your formats, test the following in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
    string[] format = new string[] { "d/MMM/yy h:m:s tt","d-MMM-yy h:m:s tt" }; 
    //                                         ^                   ^
    //                                         +------ here -------+
    string strDate = "24-May-13 12:03:03 AM";

    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, format, provider, style, out dt))
    {
        dt.Dump();
        dt.Hour.Dump();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
24.05.2013 00:03:03
0
```

Comment: But `H` is used for 24 hours format, then why i should use `h` here.

Comment: Because you're not parsing 24-hour formats. You're parsing 12-hour formats. Internally the DateTime value is *stored* as something completely different that handles 24 hours just fine. It's only a parsing and display issue. Your format specified 24-hour format with AM/PM specifier, this is an incorrect combination, so switch to lowercase `h`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

> HH:mm:ss

for displaying time (along with the date) in 24 hour format.

**Warning:**

As the accepted answer pointed out, this works fine if you are trying to parse a date that is already in an 24 hour format. Otherwise, you use lowercase 'h'

Comment: see more date time formats @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: This will not parse `24-May-13 2:3:3`

Comment: @RajeevKumar simply use "H:m:s" and take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: @Rajeev Kumar, if you want to use an exact format you'll need to use it exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

string strMinFormat = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"); // 12 hours format
string strMaxFormat = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"); // 24 hours format
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that `H` looks for the hour in 24-hour-format and ignores the daypart specifier entirely. Use the 12-hour-format specifier `h` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Globalization;

//Your datetime variable value for example or you can get it from the database
//2019-05-31 03:00:00 PM
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-05-31 03:00:00 PM", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

//2019-05-31 15:00:00
string _24HoursFormat = datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//15:00:00
string _24HoursFormatTimeOnly = datetime.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```